# How can I addapt the size of 2 data frames based in the content of a column?

Tags: r

> I would like to solve this in R

I have two data frames of the different numbers of rows, and for one of the columns they have the same content but one of them with more repetitions. I would like to duplicate the row in the smaller data frame to adapt to the size of the bigger data frame whenever this happens.

So let's say the columns I want to compare loos like this

```
df_small$column2<-c("A", "B","C");
df_big$column3<-c("A", "B","B","B","C","C")
```

I would like to replicate the rows containing B two times in `df_small`, and replicate once the row containing "C". I tried something like this.

```
i=1
while (i <= nrow(df_big)) {
  if (df_big$column3[i+1]==df_small[i,2]){
    df_small<-rbind(df_small, df:small[i,1:2]) #df_small has two columns
    i=i+1
  } else{
    i=i+1
    next
  }

}
```

This is not working. I am not really familiar with loops in R and I don´t know where the mistake is. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `merge` to join the tables together.

```r
df_small <- data.frame(column1 = runif(3), 
                                             column2 = LETTERS[1:3], 
                                             column3 = rpois(3,3))
df_big <- data.frame(column1 = runif(6), 
                                         column2 = rpois(6, 3),
                                         column3 = c("A", "B","B","B","C","C"))
merge(df_small, df_big, 
            by.x = 'column2', by.y = 'column3')
#>   column2 column1.x column3 column1.y column2.y
#> 1       A 0.3445707       3 0.2213069         0
#> 2       B 0.6452454       4 0.9294447         3
#> 3       B 0.6452454       4 0.3348785         6
#> 4       B 0.6452454       4 0.5433028         3
#> 5       C 0.4662731       4 0.6461483         1
#> 6       C 0.4662731       4 0.4180109         2
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Dplyr solution:

```r
library(dplyr)
df_small <- tibble(column2 = c("A", "B","C"), col = 1:3)
df_big  <- tibble(column3 = c("A", "B","B","B","C","C"), col = 100*1:6)
inner_join(df_small, select(df_big, column3), c("column2" = "column3"))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>   column2   col
#>   <chr>   <int>
#> 1 A           1
#> 2 B           2
#> 3 B           2
#> 4 B           2
#> 5 C           3
#> 6 C           3
```

`select(df_big, column3)` is here to make sure we don't attach anything unnecessary from `df_big`.